# 3D Plot on R studio

Tags: r, plot, charts, 3d, distribution

I want to create a plot with many distribution on it. My goal is to have all these distribution on the same square 3D plot.
I have created a monte carlo distribution of Sales Turnover (ST). For each year, I have a different distribution of ST.
I want to create my plot such as:

X= Sales Turnover value;

Y= Distribution(the number of monte-carlo cases I have for each value of sales turnover);

Z= Year (1 to 10)

I tried to do that using plotly, but the result is not satisfying, the printout of the chart is not very clear.
Finally, if you have another suggestion to execute what I need, I'll be happy to hear about it. 
Thank you in advance everyone.

PS: I tried to be as clear as possible, my english is not perfect :p. Don't hesitate to comment if you have any question/added information needed to this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, provide a working minimal dataset.

Comment: @ed_sans What do you mean by a working minimal dataset? I have 200 different value for X, between 0 and 100. for each of these X, I have a Y in percent, associated. My dataset is such as: Sales Turnover 1, Distribution 1, ST2 D2,... Sales Turnover 10, Distribution 10.

Comment: "Including a minimal reproducible example in your question will increase your chances of getting a timely, useful answer." Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @ed_sans sorry I'm new here. I tried to use scatterplot3d, but the problem is that I don't have only 3 set of data, I have an X and a Y associated, 10 times, and I have no idea what function to use in that case

Comment: If you have X,Y data from 10 years, I would plot it in a scatterplot e.g. with ggplot2 using different colors for the Year.

Comment: Y1= scatterplot3d(Workbook1_1_$YEARS1, Workbook1_1_$`SALES TURNOVER 1`, Workbook1_1_$`DISTRIBUTION 1`, grid=TRUE, xlab="YEAR", ylab="Sales Turnover", zlab="Distribution", color="red", main = "YEAR1", angle=75)
Y2= scatterplot3d(Workbook1_1_$YEARS2, Workbook1_1_$`SALES TURNOVER 2`, Workbook1_1_$`DISTRIBUTION 2`, grid=TRUE, xlab="YEAR", ylab="Sales Turnover", zlab="Distribution", color="blue", main = "YEAR2", angle=75) . Okay so I have these two scatterplot3d, please please tell me how to merge them in the same square. @ed_sans